# Swift: Generic parameter could not be inferred

Tags: swift

I got an error when compiling:

```
var beaconIDs = [BeaconID]()
for i in 0..<BeaconsStruct.uuidT.count {
beaconIDs.append(BeaconID(UUIDString: BeaconsStruct.uuidT[i], major:  
Int(BeaconsStruct.majorT[i])!, minor: Int(BeaconsStruct.minorT[i])!))
}
```

The error is: Generic parametrer "Element" could not be inferred.

BeaconID contains:

```
struct BeaconID: Equatable, CustomStringConvertible, Hashable {
    let proximityUUID: UUID
    let major: CLBeaconMajorValue
    let minor: CLBeaconMinorValue

    init(proximityUUID: UUID, major: CLBeaconMajorValue, minor: CLBeaconMinorValue) {
        self.proximityUUID = proximityUUID
        self.major = major
        self.minor = minor
    }

    init(UUIDString: String, major: CLBeaconMajorValue, minor: CLBeaconMinorValue) {
        self.init(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: UUIDString)!, major: major, minor: minor)
    }
}
```

BeaconsStruct contains:

```
struct BeaconsStruct {
static var uuidT: [String] = []
static var minorT: [String] = []
static var majorT: [String] = []
static var lokalizacjaT: [String] = []
}
```

Can I please ask you for help with that?

Comment: Given the error is probably occurring in the call to create the `BeaconID`, please add that to the `BeaconID` struct code you have included.

Comment: Your BeaconID initializer makes no sense. Show it, please.

Comment: @matt BeaconID is a generic Estimote class, https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-SDK/blob/master/Examples/swift/Notification/Notification/Estimote/BeaconID.swift

Comment: It is not my job to go elsewhere to work out your code. It is your job to show enough code to allow me to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @matt, right, apologise for that. BeaconID has 2 init. ->  init(proximityUUID: UUID, major: CLBeaconMajorValue, minor: CLBeaconMinorValue) {
        self.proximityUUID = proximityUUID
        self.major = major
        self.minor = minor
    }

    init(UUIDString: String, major: CLBeaconMajorValue, minor: CLBeaconMinorValue) {
        self.init(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: UUIDString)!, major: major, minor: minor)
    }

Comment: But it has no member `UUIDString`. So how is that second initializer defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your casts for `major` and `minor` are wrong. The initializer takes `CLBeaconMajorValue` and `CLBeaconMinorValue`, so cast to those instead of casting to `Int`.

```
var beaconIDs = [BeaconID]()
for i in 0..<BeaconsStruct.uuidT.count {
    beaconIDs.append(BeaconID(UUIDString: BeaconsStruct.uuidT[i],
        major: CLBeaconMajorValue(BeaconsStruct.majorT[i])!,
        minor: CLBeaconMinorValue(BeaconsStruct.minorT[i])!))
}
```